# PyQt QTabWidget Multiple Corner WIdgets

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qtabwidget

I want to remove the actual Close, minimize and maximize buttons of a window and create my own custom buttons, just like in chrome. I therefore want to add corner widgets to my tabwidget. Is there a way so that I can add three buttons as corner widgets of a QTabWidget?
Is it somehow possible to achieve using the QHBoxLayout ?
The setCornerWidget function just takes one widget as its input.

Answer (score 5):

1. Add a generic `QWidget` as the corner widget.
2. Give it a `QHBoxLayout`.
3. Add your buttons to the layout.

I use this frequently, often by subclassing QTabWidget and creating accessor functions that return the individual buttons. Adding signals like `buttonClicked(int)` with the index and `buttonClicked(QAbstractButton)` with the button itself are helpful, too.